# How can I get visual confirmation 2 Raspberry Pi's are connected?

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, ping

I have got two raspberry pi 4 model b's and my aim is to connect them via ethernet (RJ45) on an offline environment to measure packet loss. I have set static IP's on both - 172.16.0.1 and 172.16.0.2 - and connected via ethernet.
My issue is I have no idea if they are actually connected as "$ping 172.16.0.2" from 172.16.0.1 does not do anything. But I don't see why they wouldn't be connected. Is there a way I can get a confirmation displayed when I plug the ethernet in?

From extensive research I have realised that it is much more difficult to do this without a router or any network connection which is why I have come here. I also thought that if someone else has had this issue, there will be a clear solution (links to resources to what needs to be learnt etc) on this question

TIA

Comment: Okay, then can you help me understand?

Comment: I have done a lot of research and near enough every solution requires setting a static IP, so that's what I followed. If I clearly don't have any understanding (which is obviously why I posted a question) instead of mocking it - help out.

Comment: Yes that is why I am trying to learn - I wasn't born with the knowledge. I'm sure at one point you had no understanding of it. I did ask what I was trying to achieve - connecting to pi's locally via an RJ45 in order to ping data packets between them

Comment: You need to pick an address for each end of the link from `192.168.xx.xx` (each /24 group is independent) or `172.[16-31].xx.xx` (each /16 group is independent) or `10.xx.xx.xx`  (any net mask from /8 through /31 is OK) those are routable just not on to the public internet.

Comment: No that was an error on my part - I misread a document and assigned 127.0.xx.xx when it should've been 172.16.xx.xx. The comment above just made me realise that was a mistake on my part

Comment: @Milliways I came here for help (you know that this website is used for that don't you...) not to be talked down to by you.

Answer (score 0):

Pi are DESIGNED to connect to a router but if you directly connect (with a suitable Ethernet cable) you could communicate using Link-local addresses to hostname.local (this of course assumes you have allocated distinct hostnames).

If you really want to know addresses `ip a && ip r` will show.